# Method to retrieve all items ManyToMany spring

Tags: java, spring

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "book_publisher",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    public List<Publisher> getPublishers() {
        return publishers;
    }
```

The above code shows that a book can have many publisher

```
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "publishers")
        public List<Book> getBooks() {
            return books;
        }
```

The above code shows that a publisher can have many book.

I have 2 repository as shown below.

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
}
```

////

```
public interface PublisherRepository extends JpaRepository<Publisher, Long> {
}
```

Can i know what is the method to define in each in order to retrieve all books by publisher and retrieve all publisher by books? My database is set up already. It contains the book, publisher and book_publisher table. Please help thank you.

Comment: You don're really need any method. If you have a book, and want to know all its publishers, you just call book.getPublishers(). And vice-versa. You of course also can use a query, and it's quite simple if you read the documentation about JPQL and joins. Have you done that? Have you tried anything?